# Expo XDE React-Native CAMERA_ROLL Permission `undetermined`

Tags: react-native, permissions, expo

i have created a new react native project using expo XDE and i have simply added a button to get camera roll permissions, but it gives an error: `Error: Missing camera roll permission.`

when i log the return value of the `Permissions.askAsync()` method, it tells me the permission is `{status: "undetermined", expires: "never"}`.

is it possible to explicitly go into the device's setting and allow camera roll permissions for the expo app? i am using ios simulator as the device, but i cant find the settings to allow camera roll permission.

my App.js code is as follows:

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import { Permissions, ImagePicker } from 'expo';
export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>Open up App.js to start working on your app!</Text>

        <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={() => {
                    debugger;
                    console.log(Permissions.CAMERA_ROLL)
                    return Permissions.getAsync(Permissions.CAMERA_ROLL)
                        .then((permission) => {
                            debugger;
                            return ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
                                height: '100px',
                                width: '100px',
                                base64: true
                            }).then((result) => {
                                const { base64 } = result;
                                debugger;
                                return base64;
                            }).catch((e) => {
                                console.log(e);
                                debugger;
                            });
                        }).catch((e) => {
                            console.log(e);
                            debugger;
                        });
                }}
            ><Text>get image</Text></TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

Comment: can you try it on a real device instead of ios simulator?

Comment: on the real device, the permission is returned as `{status: "denied", expires: "never"}`. i have gone into the phone settings and i can see that the settings is set to allow full expo access to `Photos`, `Camera`, `Mobile Data`.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did for a non-Expo example, using the menu bar for the Simulator and Xcode:

1. Simulator > Hardware > Erase All Content and Settings (wait for this to complete)
2. Xcode > Product > Clean (wait till completion)
3. `react-native run-ios` for a new build from terminal

Hopefully this helps.